# Colon use - Can I use a colon here?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, colons

In the sentence,

"My school requires the following: a resume and a good grades."

Can I use a colon?  I realize that grammar rules require an independent clause before the colon.  Is, "My school requires the following" an independent clause?

Comment: You're most likely to see a colon used with three or more items, and/or when it introduces a bulleted list or something like that.

Comment: Your example is right but not this one: "My school requires: a resume and a good grades." Here, "My school requires" is not a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**My school requires the following** is a grammatically complete sentence, and so is fine to be used before a colon.

However, it may flow more naturally if you choose to omit a colon entirely.

> My school requires both a resume and good grades.

*(Note the removal of "a" from "a good grades")*